# website update cache

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, css

If you have a live website (using PHP,MySQL,JS,CSS) and say you change some functionality. What is the best way to make sure, that when a user visits the site, the changed pages are updated and not loaded from cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that reson there is file loaders made for. When you load css, js or any other file, you must set cache control header. You can do it by editing .htaccess or with php.

[.htaccess](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html) demo

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A300
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A3600
ExpiresByType text/css A3600
ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
ExpiresByType image/png A604800
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800
ExpiresByType text/plain A300
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A604800
ExpiresByType video/x-flv A604800
ExpiresByType application/pdf A604800
ExpiresByType text/html A300
</IfModule>
```

[PHP](http://www.badpenguin.org/php-howto-control-page-caching) demo:

```
 $offset = 3600 * 24;
 $expire = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
 header($expire);
```

Comment: Dont forget to install mod_expires to apache. Many hoster dont support it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Looks like this could be the solution. What are the numbers for? A300 etc, is that how long to cache it in secs?

Comment: @George Yes. You can read more at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_expires.html

Comment: Yes. For any file in your server.

Comment: When i upload a picture in firefox. It works just fine, but when i upload a picture on google chrome it does not update the picture. I have to refresh the browser to get it to update. Any idea why?

Comment: I dont use Chrome much. Sorry.

Comment: Ok i'll post a new question after some testing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Via HTML, in the Head section put...

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of that. Does it just always load a fresh page if it can?

Comment: Yup, the Expires meta specifies that the page has already expired and cannot be loaded from cache. However it will NEVER cache, so even if the page hasnt changed, it will still request for a fresh one from the server

Comment: Setting everything not to cache all the time is a bad idea if the content stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really control the policy each browser, if it complies to the standards, but what commonly happens is the browser does download the header from each HTML before deciding whether or not it should be loaded from cache or re-downloaded.

Check [RFC HTTP 1.1 Header Field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more details (under cache control in particular)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some form of caching the user will be requesting data and checking if it has been updated. Usually your PHP is not cached unless you have active caching.

Your JS and CSS would have to be set via HEADERS under say Apache (or whatever web server you utilize).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the window.applicationCache.swapCache(); and window.location.reload(); to force reload the page once javascript confirms that there's an updated version of the site.

A better option may be to prompt the user in some way, letting them know that the site updated. That way, the page doesn't just suddenly reload.

```
function updateCache(){
    window.applicationCache.swapCache();
    window.location.reload();
}

window.applicationCache.addEventListener("updateready", updateCache, false);
```

Comment: Cache control MUST be made via HEADERS not javascript.

Comment: This would be used in conjunction with <html manifest="source/manifestfile.php">. I'm confused at what you're saying.

Comment: Your solution only fits live webpages where news may come in in min. or sec. But how you gonna set cache for images? And window.applicationCache only works on html5.